# Changing editing capabilities on MapInfo *.tab file using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, tab

When I load a .Tab file into QGIS I am unable to make changes to it.
The information on the MetaData Tab reads the following:

"Editing Capabilities of this layer: Add Attributes, Fast Access to Features at ID"

How can I change the Editing Capabilities so that I can edit the features with this .TAB file.

Comment: Simple answer is you can't. The mitab lib that ogr uses which qgis uses doesn't support this.

Comment: @NathanW I think that's a valid answer that should be upvoted. Please post it.

Comment: I would upvote it, but I am a newbie and not allowed to vote until I have a 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is you can't. The mitab lib that ogr uses which qgis uses doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 2.14, it is now possible to edit TAB files. It came as a bit of a surprise to me because I jumped from using QGIS 2.8 to 2.14 and didn't realise the editing capability. Very welcome for those who make extensive use of TAB files.

Answer (score 1):

FYI...It seems that you can edit MapInfo .tab files as long they are not using .dbf to store the data.  Doesn't look like it can edit those...I tested and I can edit with a .dat file, but not a .dbf file

Answer (score 0):

Why not just right click on the layer in question and save as a shapefile, then edit to your requirements then.

If you need it as a .tab you could repeat the process only choosing to save as a .tab then.

Answer (score 0):

Now in Version 2.14.1 it is possible to change the Editing Capabilities on a MapInfo Tab file. I have recently tested adding a new column to a mitab. It worked easily.

Comment: I'm using exactly version 2.18 and there is problem writing TAB files. Look at this post for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262822/qgis-not-asking-to-save-my-modified-mapinfo-tabfile