# QGIS not asking to save my modified MapInfo TABfile

Tags: qgis, mapinfo

Editing TAB files works fine from user interface and from python code too. If user click SAVE button from QGIS or from python code - it works FINE. BUT if user is closing directly QGIS application - there is not question to save changes in TAB file :( For shape files QGIS is asking before application shut down.

Any ideas?